# How to tell if a number equals another number using bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am writing a program where I have an infinite loop doing something with a stopping condition to break if some variable `a == 1` using only bitwise operators.

How would I do this?

Example code:

```
while(1){
    int a;
    //do some work
    if (a==1){ // how do I say this with bitwise operators and no "!"
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: XOR (`^`) will produce zero result if all bits of two variables are equal

Comment: Can you explain what the *point* of this is? Why does it matter how you determine whether or not `a` is equal to 1?

Comment: I am doing a project where I can only use bitwise operators ... that is why I am using them.

Comment: I don't see any way to do this with *only* bitwise operators. After you use the bitwise operator, you have to compare the result with something, and that will be a normal `==` operator.

Comment: Perhaps with an `if else`: `if (a^b) { /* Not equal. Do nothing */} else { /* Equal. Do something */}`.

Comment: `if ((a^1)==0) {...}`.

Comment: `==` is kind of a bitwise operator, in that it compares each bit.

Comment: The variable a is an int

Comment: Chux that is exactly what I needed ... totally slipped my mind I could use a do-while.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OP's stopping condition is at the end of the loop, code can use a `do()` loop.

```
int a;
do {
  // some work that sets `a`
} while (a^1);
```

When `a` has the value of 1, `a ^ 1` --> `0`.

Comment: Thanks ... does exactly what I was trying to do.